# What is the total cost of a software patent and design in UK and USA?

Tags: filing

What is the total cost of filing a software patent and/or design in UK and in USA?

I mean, the fees for filing, the agency fees for writing the documents, etc. in total.

Answer (score 2):

Patent fees are spelled out on the [USPTO website](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/qs/ope/fee031913.htm).

As for lawyer or agent fees, that is outside the scope of this site and you can try contacting some directly. But starting at $10,000 ~ $30,000 would be my ballpark estimate based on what I've heard.

Comment: The USPTO fees are published but can be confusing.  Assuming you qualify as a "small entity" it is about $750 to file. The next typical step is getting a rejection. If each rejection is properly responded to within 3 months there is no USPTO fee. To keep playing after 2 rejections you need to file a request for about  $700. If you get a notice of allowance there is a publication fee of about $300 + issue fee of about $800 for the patent to issue. You are good for 3 years until a relatively low maintainance fee is due. The are larger ones at 7 years and 11 years.